# Filter the result set of a stored proc using a where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to filter the resultset of a stored procedure. What I'd like is something like the following (non-working) syntax:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM  (EXEC  sp_linkedservers) WHERE srv_name = 'myServer' )
    PRINT N'dropping linked servers'
GO
```

edit - this is just one example, I'd like a general solution if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
-- add 'loopback' linkedserver 
if exists (select * from master..sysservers where srvname = 'loopback')
    exec sp_dropserver 'loopback'
go
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'loopback',
    @srvproduct = N'',
    @provider = N'SQLOLEDB', 
    @datasrc = @@servername
go

select * into #t from openquery(loopback, 'set fmtonly on exec sp_who') 
select * from #t
drop table #t
go
```

Comment: so why exactly is this downvoted when it's the only way in sql server that you can do exactly what you want?

Comment: No offense, that is clever, but there are a couple reasons - openquery can be a security problem, so on many systems it's switched off; making a linked server is overkill for this problem; IMHO you are using a "side effect" of linked servers and openquery that others would not expect to see

Comment: that is completely true. i've assumed that the OP has a situation where he doesn't always know the exact output of a stored procedure. if you do know that then the declare table first and insert into from sproc is a great solution. if not then my suggestion is the only viable way.

Answer (score 12):

You could put the results of the stored procedure into a temporary table or table variable before this then query that table, applying whatever where clause to that you want.

**[Edited]**

Like this:

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE
(
SRV_NAME NVARCHAR(100),
SRV_PROVIDERNAME NVARCHAR(100),
SRV_PRODUCT NVARCHAR(100),
SRV_DATASOURCE NVARCHAR(100),
SRV_PROVIDERSTRING NVARCHAR(100),
SRV_LOCATION NVARCHAR(100),
SRV_CAT NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @foo
EXEC  sp_linkedservers

SELECT * FROM @foo WHERE SRV_PRODUCT = 'SQL Server'
```

You would, of course, change that final where clause to what you would want to filter on.

Comment: On SQL 2000 you'd need to use a temp table instead of a table variable

Comment: and is there no way to do it w/o declaring the schema of the result set?

Comment: This might not work when the stored procedure contains an INSERT-EXEC statement. Because that kind of sentences can not be nested.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want it for the exact purpose outlined in your question, and not a general solution, then you could just query sys.servers (SQL 2005+) (or sysservers pre 2005), no need to use the sp_linkedservers stored procedure:

```
-- SQL 2005+
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sys.servers WHERE name = 'myServer' )
    PRINT N'dropping linked servers'
GO

-- SQL 2000
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sysservers WHERE srvname = 'myServer' )
    PRINT N'dropping linked servers'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the stored procedure to a table-valued user defined function.  Keep the existing stored procedure, but just have it call this new function rather than duplicating the logic. Then use the function in your query.

Comment: It's a system stored proc. Can't change it.

Comment: Also this might not work if the stored procedure uses temporary tables. Because user defined functions can not use temporary tables.